# Reading from/writing to files using functions

Tags: c++, function

Hi I am working on a simple wage application. The following code contains a two option menu using switch statements. The code is also linked to a text file called "shop-account". The file simply contains the value 100.

For option 1 the user is suppose to be able to transfer an amount from the file. The user should be able to make as many transfers as they choose without overdrawing the account. And the code should be able to output the current balance. I believe I am suppose to be using the void function but I have never used it before and am really struggling. I was hoping someone could look at the code and tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks

```
int read_balance (void);
void write_balance (int balance);

using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int selection;
    int total;
    int balance;
    int NewAmount;

    do {
            cout << "1. Transfer an amount" <<endl;
            cout << "2. Quit" << endl;
            cout << "Please enter menu number"<<endl;
            cin >> selection;

            switch(selection)
            {
                case 1: 
                    cout << "You have choosen to transfer an amount" << endl;
                    cout << "How much do you wish to transfer from the shop account?"<<endl;
                    cin >> NewAmount;
                    balance -= NewAmount;
                    write_balance (balance);
                    cout << balance << endl;
                    break;

                case 2:
                return 0;
                break;

                default:
                cout << "Ooops, invalid selection!" << endl;
                break;
                }

        }while(selection != 2);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


int read_balance (void)
{
    fstream f;
    f.open("shop-account.txt");
    f >> balance; //error: "balance" is unidentified
    f.close();
    return balance;
}


void write_balance (int balance)
{
    fstream f;
    f.open("shop-account.txt");
    f << balance;
    f.close();
}
```

Comment: I was hoping you could look at the code and tell us where you think you are going wrong. Thanks

Comment: also the only piece of code i'm looking help with is how to actually transfer an amount from the file, once I figure this out I will continue to try and do the rest myself

Comment: missing indentation and the fact that it's not a compilable example account as "where are you going wrong"? - in your `read_balance`, where's `balance`? no where. Add `int balance;` into the function.

Comment: You could have just posted the `read_balance` function.  In fact you can still edit your post to only that code.  And just ask "why is balance unidentified here?"

Answer (score 3):

1. Like others mentioned, you didn't declare the `int balance` in the right scope (function level scope, in this case).

   In fact, it looks like you forgot call `read_balance` alltogether, so your calculations on `balance` used an *indeterminate value*, which is [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
2. Next up: declare your variables where they are used, that way you prevent this whole situation when you decide to extract pieces of code into subfunctions, and it gets easier to see where variables are used. Consequently, it gets easier to see whether the code is correct.
3. Next: Error handling. If you have none, your program is worthless. In fact, even when fixing the above issue,

   - simply entering invalid input once would run a loop and just keep substracting *indeterminate values* from the account balance **and writing those wrong values to disk**. That's probably not what you wanted.
   - making the `shop-account.txt` read-only was enough to fool the program into

     - transfer unlimited amounts without updating the file
     - having the wrong idea of the balance in the file (since it never checks)

Here is a cleaned-up version that does a minimum amount of checking, and adds an option to just 'check the account balance'. Seemed useful.

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fcfac9fa2df65169)**

I hope some of this helps. For one thing, I hope your teacher was going to mention most of this :/

```
int  read_balance(void);
void write_balance(int balance);

#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    while(std::cin.good())
    {
        std::cout << "0. Request balance"       << std::endl;
        std::cout << "1. Transfer an amount"    << std::endl;
        std::cout << "2. Quit"                  << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Please enter menu number" << std::endl;

        int selection = 2;
        if(std::cin >> selection)
        {
            std::cout << "DEBUG: selection:" << selection << "\n";
            switch(selection)
            {
            case 0:
                std::cout << "The current account balance is " << read_balance() << std::endl;
                break;

            case 1:
                {
                    std::cout << "You have choosen to transfer an amount" << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "How much do you wish to transfer from the shop account?"<<std::endl;

                    int amount = 0;
                    if (std::cin >> amount)
                    {
                        std::cout << "DEBUG: amount:" << amount << "\n";
                        int balance = read_balance();
                        if(amount<=0)
                        {
                            std::cout << "Amount must be positive\n";
                        }
                        else if(balance < amount)
                        {
                            std::cout << "Insufficient funds\n";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int new_balance = balance - amount;
                            write_balance(new_balance);
                            std::cout << "New account balance: " << new_balance << std::endl;
                        }
                    } else
                    {
                        // bad input cleared outside the switch
                    }
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                return 0;
                break;

            default:
                std::cout << "Ooops, invalid selection!" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(std::cin.eof())
        {
            std::cout << "Bye\n";
            return 0;
        }
        if(std::cin.fail())
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(99999, '\n');
            std::cout << "Invalid input\n";
            // note eof() can be true here
        }
    }
}

#include <fstream>

int read_balance(void)
{
    std::ifstream f;
    f.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
    f.open("shop-account.txt");
    int balance;
    f >> balance;
    f.close();
    return balance;
}

void write_balance(int balance)
{
    std::ofstream f;
    f.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
    f.open("shop-account.txt");
    f << balance;
    f.close();
}
```

Comment: Don't you think this is too much? OP clearly has no idea about programming, as he can't even properly initialize variables inside functions. And now you are throwing at him exceptions. And this "Before ignore: " - it's very not clear what your intent is here (I know, you know, but will beginning programmer know?)

Comment: @zoska don't you think your comment is a bit ludicrous? They're learning to program. In C++. Of course you tell them how to use C++. To program. (Removing those debug left-overs of course. As you can see, I tend to _test my answers well_ :))

Comment: @zoska: How much is too much? You want to provide crap code just because someone hasn't seen good code? When you think they should start seeing good code, then?

Comment: <pedantic nonsense>Minor problem with your first point. §3.3.5/1: "Only labels have function scope."</pedantic nonsense>

Comment: Right. It's block scope here, I believe. (Not sure what "function level scope" is and the standard doesn't know either...)

Comment: @sehe: Don't worry, I understand that some people are afraid of the truth. :)

Comment: @zoska: An example that newcomers have any chance of understanding is crap code (often). They have to see good code to learn what it looks like. We are teachers, not a crap code factory.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, giving OP answer with exceptions not being handled in any way, not saying a word about it it's really the best way to teach. Give OP good code that he will probably ignore. I give up discussion with your egos.

Comment: @zoska I didn't "not say anything about it". I'm saying I modified the code to do a ***minimum*** of error checking. In the process I show how to use `if(stream)` style, `.bad()`, `.fail()` and `.eof()` _correctly_ and the alternative style of error reporting using c++ exceptions as well. Anyone interested in learning will read more here than in browsing several "quick" and "clear" answers scattered across the site. If the OP doesn't ask himself the questions, that's not because I'm showing the wrong stuff. Also, exceptions are _not_ advanced. IOStream exceptions are just relatively underrated

Answer (score 1):

your function does not have a balance varible declartion !! you have to add a balance declaration in your function

```
int read_balance(void)
{
    fstream f;
    f.open("shop-account.txt");

    int balance;
    f >> balance; //now it's defined 
    f.close();
    return balance;
}
```

Comment: This only answers half of the problem. Assuming that the OP wanted a program that... _makes sense_

Comment: some stream error checking would be nice

Comment: @zoska: Don't you think this is too much?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what's the point of your comment?

Comment: @zoska: To point out the hypocrisy of yours. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Enlighten me, as I don't know how 'handle the errors and explain it' is the same as 'throw at OP exceptions without single word of it'. So how it's the same?

Comment: @zoska: He's just setting the exception flags on the stream, so that if a file operation fails, the OP will see an unhandled exception error, then he can ask about _that_ (or research it). That's as opposed to errors going _silent_ and causing the OP much pain and never coming across how to do things properly. Calm down.